# How can I animate the process of word reconstruction using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, text

I have a word and a list of its subwords. Is it possible to show how the word is compiling from its subwords?

In other words, I'd like to animate the process of reconstruction in the following way:
 1. the word = "abcc";
 2. list of subwords = {"ab", "bc", "cc"};
 3. At the first step the subword "ab" shows;
 4. Next, "bc" at the list of subwords highlights and substitute "b" in the previous subword, so at the screen there is "abc" now;
 5. After that the "cc" highlights and substitute letter "c" in the "abc";
 6. To sum up, there is "abcc" at the screen now.

How should I approach this problem? I am going to use this ([Textbox Text-Color Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079644/textbox-text-color-animation)) solution to change the color of different parts in the final word, but I can't understand the way to animate other parts of process. By the way, can I also show lines between subwords and words during the process of reconstruction?

Comment: wpf OR winforms? With WPF you would have built-in animation functionality, while with winforms you would have to work with a timer.

Comment: @Mathis to be honest, I don't know for sure what is the proper way to do things like this, however, I was going to use WPF.

Comment: Have a look at how you should ask questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This doesn't really fit.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid thank you, I will fix my question soon.

Comment: @valzevul That is probably why someone down voted you. I'll upvote once you have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try turning your string into a char array, and then cycle it where you increment each char into where you want to show it while pausing it with a Thread.Sleep for a couple of miliseconds:

```
string a = "Hello World!";
char[] b = a.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
   textblock1.Text+=a[i];
   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

What I forgot to mention, be sure to make this function on a separate thread, else your application is waiting for the cycle to end which would seem like to the user that the application is hanging.

With the current state of my sample code it would happen that the application would hang for 100 miliseconds for each char your string contains, which would be a loss of 1 second and 200 miliseconds.